# Excel interprets "20" entered as year in the DATE() function as 1920 instead of 2020

Tags: microsoft-excel

I tried to convert dates with two-digit year (e.g. 20) into standard dates with four digit year by using the `DATE()` function.

When a date has e.g. the year "20" (current year), Excel interprets this as "1920", e.g. `=DATE(20,1,1)` results in "1920-01-01". Why is this?

The setting for how to interpret years in "Regional Settings" is set to "1951 to 2050" so Excel should not do this.

I'm using Microsoft Office 365 Version 2004.

Comment: I assume the data existed before you changed the regional settings. so the underlying date is saved in the period before change. you can test it with changing the Regional Settings and create a new document, enter two-year dates and convert and I assume you will get the expected results.

Comment: See if this helps https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349  As per this If year is between 0 (zero) and 1899 (inclusive), Excel adds that value to 1900 to calculate the year. For example, DATE(108,1,2) returns January 2, 2008 (1900+108).

Comment: The rule you cite in your question applies to dates that are entered directly into worksheet cells.  To understand how a particular function works, you need to examine HELP for that function.  And the link provided from @patkim explains that what you see is normal behavior for the `DATE` function.

Comment: You guys are obviously right. I was so convinced, that all Date related functions are using the system setting, that I actually didn't check the specific help for this function. Only MS knows why this function behaves different than everything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a behavior of the DATE function specifically and doesn't refer to the system Calendar settings or Excel's general interpretation of dates.

[DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349)

The year parameter can be between 1 and 4 digits. Specifically and per @patkim's comment on your post:

> If year is between 0 (zero) and 1899 (inclusive), Excel adds that
> value to 1900 to calculate the year. For example, DATE(108,1,2)
> returns January 2, 2008 (1900+108).

So, a 2-digit number will be added to 1900 to get the year.

So, instead of considering the first parameter of the DATE function as a year when entering a 2-digit number, it may be more helpful to think of it as "years since 1900".

If you are using DATE to convert an actual date from another cell into a new date from the same year, then consider something like this:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)
```

This will also work to get 2020:

```
=DATE(120,1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that explains it! Should've looked there first. Just couldn't imagine such an inconsistency...

Answer (score 2):

This is normal.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/2-digit-year-when-importing/m-p/65676

> To ensure that year values are interpreted as you intended, type year
> values as four digits (for example, 2001, not 01). By entering
> four-digit years, Excel won't interpret the century for you.

I find that using 4-digit years is better overall (for our clients and ourselves) to avoid confusion and to leave Windows date settings as default.

Comment: the OP is aware and you answer does not relate to his question why excel does not use the system setting and the link you shared has the explanation that if you change the regional settings that ALL MS apps will comply. "In Microsoft Windows, you can change the way two-digit years are interpreted for all Microsoft Windows programs that you have installed." from same link....

Comment: We are just better off to use 4-digit years rather than changing Windows - my viewpoint at least,

Comment: I agree with that since 1993 :) - just saying it did not answer OP's Q.

Comment: Consider OP's situation... they may have a whole load of existing data with 2-digit years. Saying "_IMO we should use 4-digit years_" isn't helpful, and your answer doesn't address the configuration changes they've made that supposedly contradicts the observed behaviour...

Comment: We have used date conversions in one application we converted a while back.

Comment: I agree 100% that one should always use 4 digit dates. However, if you export data from some 3rd party application and you end up with thousands of datasets containing only 2 digit years.... what shall I do?

Comment: That would fall into a programming or conversion job. Conversion: export the date data to a text column (2-digits) and have a routine (Excel in a simple situation) to add 20 to the front, or another routine like that. Alter the 3rd party application if you can (ask the vendor). We did the same thing at the end of 1999.

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware, there are at least two ways of entering a date with two digits as year.

if you type:

```
1/1/20
```

The Excel UI will honor the Windows Regional Settings, and display:

```
1/1/2020
```

*( or the assigned format)* If, however, you use the `DATE()` worksheet function and enter:

```
=DATE(20,1,1)
```

The Windows Regional Setting may not be honored and the UI will interpret as:

```
1/1/1920
```

*(I have never asked the question "why")*